# Repeated measures ANOVA instead of t-pair and t-independent

Tags: repeated-measures

when  have two groups: control nd experiment and two measurement at pre and post test, in this condition  can i use repeated measures ANOVA istead of t-pair and independent

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data are normal and variances are equal, an ANOVA should be OK.
Suppose you have $n = 20$ students, then the model would be

$$Y_{ijk} = \mu + \alpha_i + S(\alpha)_{j(i)} + \tau_k + (\alpha\tau)_{ik} + e_{ijk},$$
where $i = 1,2$ groups (Expt and Ctrl), $j(i) = 1, \dots, 20$ Students
within each group (40 in all), and $k = 1, 2$ tests (Pre and Post). $S(\alpha)$ is a random factor nested within groups, $\alpha$ and $\tau$ are fixed effects and $(\alpha\tau)$ is their interaction.

If you have different numbers of students in each group, you should make sure your software can accommodate that (perhaps with a general linear model).  If students were randomized into the two groups, I suppose their variability within each group will be equal.

A potentially important advantage
of using this ANOVA model (over a combination of one and two sample t tests) is the ability to test for interaction (the difference between Pre and Post tests may differ according to groups).

Comment: You seem to be ignoring "two measurement at pre and post test"

Comment: I took it to mean two measurements (one pre and one post), hence $k = 1,2.$ Description is a bit telegraphic.

Comment: [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anova). [Repeated measures ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design#Repeated_measures_ANOVA).

Comment: @Alexis: Seems clear you have a different interpretation. If you have an Answer to go with it, I'd be happy to see that. // One difficulty is that in different fields of application 'repeated measures' can describe a vast variety of models.

Comment: I am explaining my downvote. ANOVA does not in any way address the reduced variance obtained in repeated measures designs (including the OP's pre-post measures).